# Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I recently started getting this error on my WebAPI project on VS 2017. If I run the same project on another machine it works fine. I have tried reinstalling VS 2017, reinstalling .net 4.0 and 4.5. I also tried changing the project target to 4.7 in which nothing worked. This is a similar issue but I am not running .net core 2.0 ([ASP.NET Core 2.0 Could not load file or assembly System.ServiceModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45823454/asp-net-core-2-0-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-servicemodel)) Any help will be much appreciated.

I also tried adding this DLL to the project and adding it via the webconfig but didn't change anything.

The DLL is on my system -> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.ServiceModel.dll

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its
>   dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file
>   or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The
>   module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' could not be loaded.
>
> Assembly manager loaded from: 
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll Running under
>   executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe
>   --- A detailed error log follows.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089  (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/Users/Michael/Desktop/Project/API/ LOG:
>   Initial PrivatePath = C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\Project\API\bin Calling assembly : (Unknown).
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\Project\API\web.config LOG: Using host configuration file:
>   C:\Users\Michael\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config LOG: Using
>   machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Post-policy reference: System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The
>   module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.]
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +36
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +152
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +21    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +28
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The
>   module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.]
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +738
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo
>   ai) +57
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +170
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies()
>   +92    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String
>   preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +290
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +157
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +549
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The
>   module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +10042604
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +95
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +254

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up copying the "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET" directory from a friends computer and it worked fine after that. Very strange.