# .NET Core 2.0 console app: Could not load file or assembly System.ServiceModel version 3.0.0.0

Tags: wcf, .net-core, .net-3.5

Possibly related to [ASP.NET Core 2.0 Could not load file or assembly System.ServiceModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45823454/asp-net-core-2-0-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-servicemodel)

We are currently developing a console app using .NET Core 2.0 as framework that references a .NET Framework 3.5 WCF library.

When we execute the console app an error appears in the debug output:

Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.

What do we have to do to get this assembly visible to the Dotnet Core 2.0 console app?

Comment: We had problem with  packages in our sngular .bet core project after migration. Visual 2017 update helped us :) If uou dont have newest version try to update